# How to get Button click response from email to my webpage in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a web application,where new user registers with details.After he clicks submit button,an email verification link sent to his mail and also his details are sent to my CEO in order to approve the user by clicking the button Approve.
  Here how do I get button click response from CEO mail to my web page for updating the new user as valid in DB.

Answer (score 0):

In general you need the same logic as for user email confirmation. You need to insert a button link in CEO mail that directs to your site action or page.

This link should contain a unique id like Guid or similar. Then you will identify a user by this link and will approve it.

It's too general question actually. Maybe you have a problem with a specific step of this task?